# Fechar aplicacao em PHP-GUI

Tags: php

Utilizando [PHP-GUI](https://github.com/gabrielrcouto/php-gui/), inicio uma applicação assim:

```
$app = new \Gui\Application([
    'title' => 'G.M Personal APP',
    'left' => 248,
    'top' => 50,
    'width' => 860,
    'height' => 600,
    'icon' => realpath(__DIR__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'G.M-=icon.png'
]);
$app->on('start', function() use ($app) {

        $button = new Button([
            'value' => 'Fechar aplicação',
            'top' => 160,
            'left' => 50,
            'width' => 450
        ]);


        $button->on('click', function () use ($button, $app) 
        {
            //Aqui eu quero fechar a janela/aplicação e abrir o terminal
        });
});       
$app->run();
```

Isso me da como resposta :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui] isso de resposta:

A dúvida é:

> Usando [essa biblioteca](https://github.com/gabrielrcouto/php-gui) (a mesma usada a cima), como encerrar essa aplicacao ?

Comment: Já tentou `$app->terminate();` ?

Comment: Pelo que vejo pela documentação poderá ser `$app->fire("exit");`

Comment: @gato sim, não finaliza nada

Comment: @lazyFox também não funciona, acho que seja com o método fire, mas ainda sim não está dando

Comment: @AnthraxisBR você verificou se o evento click esta sendo disparado corretamente? Não seira necessário importar o `Button` do namespace `Gui\Components\Button;` ?

Comment: @gato o 'click' dispara sim, o uso dos namespace tão indicados antes, eu consigo ter qualquer outra interação, o problema esté em como encerrar a apliacação só, nenhum dos dois metodos aq de cima dos comentarios devolve erro ou sucesso, mas qualquer outra interação do 'on click' q tentei funcionam

Comment: Tambéms tens a variável protected `$running` dentro da `Gui\Application` **Defines if the application is running**

Comment: [Vê se isto ajuda](https://github.com/gabrielrcouto/php-gui/pull/108/files) têm aí vários métodos interessantes

Comment: @lazyFox usando os status 'running' da aplicação, com ->terminate() ele sai do processo rodando no terminal, mas não fecha a interface

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode usar o método [**`Gui\Application::terminate()`**](https://github.com/gabrielrcouto/php-gui/blob/master/src/Application.php#L347):

```
$button->on('click', function () use ($button, $app) {
    $app->terminate();
});
```

Ou pode experimentar o método [**`Gui\Application::sendCommand`**](https://github.com/gabrielrcouto/php-gui/blob/master/src/Application.php#L364):

```
$button->on('click', function () use ($button, $app) {
    $app->sendCommand("exit", [], function () {
        echo 'Fechou';
    });
});
```

https://github.com/gabrielrcouto/php-gui/blob/master/src/Application.php#L347